# C++ Adapter - For Methods With Same Name But Different Return Type

Tags: c++, boost, adapter

I've been trying to find an Adapter solution in C++ to two external interfaces, which are so similar but differs in return types in enumerations.

```
enum
{
   SAME_VALUE1,
   SAME_VALUE2
} EnumTypeA

enum
{
   SAME_VALUE1,
   SAME_VALUE2,
   DIFFERENT_VALUE3
} EnumTypeB

class A // not inherited
{
    EnumTypeA Method();
}

class B // not inherited
{
    EnumTypeB Method();
}
```

Do you have any idea about a solution so I can use a wrapper to call either interface A or B?

```
ReturnType? MyAdapter::Method()
{
// Call Method from A or B but how
}
```

Regards,
Burak

Note Added: I've solved the problem using Boost.Variant

Comment: Have you tried templates?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of calling Method in an adapter using templates?

Comment: In reality it is probably more complex, but from your example it is not clear why `MyAdapter` doesn't just return `EnumTypeB`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to write a function that has variable return type. Therefore I would recommend something like following:

```
enum ReturnTypeEnum
{
    ReturnTypeA,
    ReturnTypeB
};

struct ReturnType
{
    ReturnTypeEnum actualType;
    union 
    {
        EnumTypeA a;
        EnumTypeB b;
    }actualValue;
}

ReturnType MyAdapter::Method()
{
    ReturnType retval;

    //Call method from A or B, whichever necessary
    //and construct retval accordingly.

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Adapter interface with its own return value.

```
struct Adapter
{
    virtual ~Adapter() {}

    enum Enum {
        VALUE1,
        VALUE2,
        VALUE3,
    };

    virtual Enum Method( ) = 0;
};
```

then create an Adapter for A and B.

```
struct AdapterA : public Adapter {
    Enum Method( ) override { return Enum( a.Method() ); };    
    A a;
};

struct AdapterB : public Adapter {
    Enum Method( ) override { return Enum( b.Method() ); };    
    B b;
};
```

These will most likely need to be in separate implementation files so the `SAME_VALUE1` don't clash wile compiling. Then you can do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<Adapter> drv;

drv.reset( new AdapterA() );
drv->Method();

drv.reset( new AdapterB() );
drv->Method();
```